# MinIO HTTPResponse | Decode into Dataframe or Excel

Tags: python-3.x, excel, dataframe, httpresponse, minio

Goal: create either a Dataframe in memory or store file locally.

Struggling to decode Excel files; I can decode all other file types.

Code:

```py
from MinioConn import MinioConn
from io import StringIO
import pandas as pd
import os

client = MinioConn().client()
obj = client.get_object('bucket-name', 'dir/file.xls')

print(type(obj))
print(obj.read())

filename = 'temp.xlsx'
new_file = open(filename, 'w')
try:
    new_file.write(obj.response)  # .content
    new_file.close()
    df = pd.read_excel(filename)
except:
    os.remove(filename)
```

Traceback:

```
<class 'urllib3.response.HTTPResponse'>
2\n\x00q\x0b\x00\x00@\x00\x00\x00,@\xfd\x00\n\x00q\x0b\x01\x00\x0f\x00\xc2\x02\x00\x00\xfd\x00\n\x ...
```

Please let me know if I should add anything else to post/ clarify.

Comment: Informally, you could export **each sheet as a `.csv`** and to have on MinIO / S3. Whether there's open source code to do upload and download on batch idk.